# Can't get the authenticated user cookie session to be used when creating a new node via Services 3 endpoint

Tags: services, 8, sessions, cookies

My application is sending this header to Service 3 endpoint when creating a new node:

```
{
  'Cookie': 'SESS255f42d9a87a0df5bf8959d25909fe8c=St8o29NI9Hx84kPo8NuZbpdHWuRgNSS9qy9cQ-QM4rA; expires=Sun, 15-Jun-2014 00:39:27 GMT; path=/; domain=.mydomain.local; HttpOnly',
  'Content-type': 'application/json'
}
```

Nonetheless, the newly created node user is set to anonymous.

Is there anything wrong with the header I am sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I should've had checked **Session authentication** at `admin/structure/services/list/MYENDPOINT/edit`